# How to use the GOTO labels?

Tags: sql-server

All the labels are getting executed. How do I solve this?

Both Yes and no are getting printed.

```
declare @x as varchar(max)
set @x =5
if (@x>4)
begin 
goto t1
end
else
begin
goto t2
end

t1:
print('yes')

t2:
print ('no')
```

I want only Yes as output.

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? They’re completely different products. But the main problem is you don’t exit anywhere. Code continues to run until it gets to the end so both are printed. Labels don’t act as barriers

Comment: Using GOTO if it is not necessary is considered as a bad practice. You can create temp procs or do stuff in if.

Answer (score 0):

You should go to the end after print.

```
declare @x as varchar(max)
set @x =5

if (@x>4)
begin 
  goto t1
end
else
begin
  goto t2
end

t1:
print('yes')
goto tend

t2:
print ('no') 
goto tend

tend:
```